# What are the metallic rods near the Pilot's head in a TIE fighter?

Tags: star-wars

Early depictions of the cockpit of TIE fighters and Darth Vader's TIE Advanced have an assembly of metallic rods with rounded ends pointed at the temples of the pilot's head. These objects are usually just out of shot and so, I think, has been left out of a lot of Fan art.

I wonder if they are some sort of proximity or missile lock warning device as they are perfectly positioned in the corners of the pilot's peripheral vision. They are there in all the production photos for ANH and be seen in the movies.

[image: A screen cap of ANH, showing the rods in the top left and right corners]

What are these rods?

[image: A computer model of a TIE cockpit, showing the assembly quite clearly]

Comment: Could you draw a freehand red circle around the rods? Or find a less dark image?

Comment: I doubt you'll find a canonical or scientific explanation. My bet is the boring explanation that someone during movie recording went: "hey I found this strange junk, maybe we use it for cool cockpit stuff?" Much like how a whole lot of other things were added to the original movies.

Comment: They can be seen in the cockpit in the game "Star Wars: Squadrons" which launched today.  I haven't had a chance to play enough yet to see whether they actually do anything, or are just decorations.

Comment: There are two distinctive structures overhead on the ceiling to the left and right of the forward viewport. Each of these objects consists of a cluster of four rounded metal rods pointing directly out of the wall. The rods are silvery, about two centimetres thick and at least fifteen centimetres long. Their function is unknown. https://www.theforce.net/swtc/tie.html

Comment: Also you may try to look for "Star Wars: Tie Fighter: Owners' Workshop Manual", there is a "cockpit page", but I just don't know if there is a description of those rods...

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi - There's nothing in that book that explains what they are, nor in the *Star Wars: Incredible Cross Sections* books

Comment: Thanks to all the answers.  I'm working on a 1:10 scale CAD model of a TIE fighter https://a360.co/2GxbEkU and would love to hear what people thought the purpose of these could be. I love thinking about how SCI FI machines function, even if there is a measure of magic in there.  If you had to guess, what do you think the function is?

Comment: The one interesting fact is that at some moment one of the rods seems to be broken, i.e. not pointing at the pilot. It just hanging suspended )

Comment: It could be some kind of brain wave reader-translator, that could, for instance, trigger some injection in case if pilot lost consciousness. Or maybe it just reads brain waves to confirm that pilot proceeds with the order from supreme commander.

Comment: The first case could be know to the pilot, and so he is happy with that backup. And the second one is known to the commander only. So he could terminate that pilot or even the whole TF in case... )

Comment: What do people think about the idea of these being a light up proximity alert? The visibility out the view port of all TIEs is extremely limited for a fighter craft. These rods would be just inside the pilot's peripheral vision and each could light up as a bogie was detected in a particular sector around the craft. The intensity or shade of the light could indicate range. Many of the Star Wars piloting video games have flashing proximity alert lights and some have a dedicated 360 radar style display but i don't think there was anything like this in episodes 4,5 or 6.

Comment: Probably just spare [inanimate carbon rods](https://simpsons.fandom.com/wiki/Inanimate_carbon_rod) — they're great, and they can come in pretty handy in space.